# Can't checkout a new branch from remote

Tags: git

I did this:

```
git fetch --all
Fetching origin
remote: Counting objects: 242, done.
............
From bitbucket.org:xxx/xxx
   xxxx..xxxx  develop    -> origin/develop
 * [new branch]      branch1 -> origin/branch1
   xxxx..xxxx  master     -> origin/master
```

And then I did:

```
git checkout branch1
error: pathspec 'branch1' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

But should've checked out to branch1. What's up with this?

Comment: Have you committed anything to your repository?

Comment: Could you please add the output of `git branch -a` to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no local branch called `branch1`. You need to say

```
git checkout -b branch1 origin/branch1
```

This creates a local branch called branch1 that tracks the remote branch `branch1`.

Comment: Usually, one wouldn't need to do this.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, what's needed then?

Comment: Take Noufal's suggestion, but make the option -tb instead of -b, that'll make your local branch a tracking branch.

Comment: is there any difference between origin/branch1 and remotes/origin/branch1?

Comment: @DonBranson, won't it track the remote/branch1 by default?

Comment: I've not seen it do that. Maybe the current versions do that automatically, and I'm still using the old syntax. Just try it and see.

Comment: Oh, and @AlexanderSupertramp - don't eat the berries. :(

Comment: The branch should have been created when fetching from the repository, IIRC.

Comment: @wei2912, local branches are not created on fetch.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp - You're right - with the syntax given in the answer, it will create a tracking branch, since both the new local name and the existing remote name are provided.

Comment: @DonBranson, so -t is not necessary but won't cause damage?

Comment: `-t` is useful if you're going to regularly use this branch to fetch changes from the corresponding remote branch. If it's a throwaway branch that you just need to, for example, manage a pull request, you don't need the `-t`.

Answer (score 1):

From experimentation:

```
[wei2912@localhost wee-repo]$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/wei2912/tmp/wee-repo/.git/
[wei2912@localhost wee-repo]$ git checkout -b branch1
Switched to a new branch 'branch1'
[wei2912@localhost wee-repo]$ git checkout -b master
Switched to a new branch 'master'
[wei2912@localhost wee-repo]$ git checkout branch1
error: pathspec 'branch1' did not match any file(s) known to git.
[wei2912@localhost wee-repo]$ git branch -a
[wei2912@localhost wee-repo]$
```

You cannot create more than one branch before the initial commit (which makes sense if you think about it). You will need to checkout to a branch and make a commit to that branch before you can create other branches that branch out from the initial branch (the branch which you've chosen to make a commit to).

```
[wei2912@localhost wee-repo]$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
[wei2912@localhost wee-repo]$ touch test.txt
[wei2912@localhost wee-repo]$ git add test.txt
[wei2912@localhost wee-repo]$ git branch -a
* master
[wei2912@localhost wee-repo]$ git checkout -b branch1
Switched to a new branch 'branch1'
[wei2912@localhost wee-repo]$ git branch -a
* branch1
  master
```

As you can see, after making the initial commit, you can then create branches that branch off the `master` branch.

NOTE: This is under the assumption that you have not yet committed anything to your repository. If you have not, please notify me and I'll edit/delete my answer.

Comment: It seems clear that the OP's repo has multiple commits (from the output of `git fetch --all` shown in the question).